# pandas Dataframe: How do I find the count of specific value (say 'Unavailable') across all columns (numeric and non numeric) of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Let's say I have replaced all null values in my dataframe with a string ('Unavailable') using df.fillna('Unavailable'). I now need to double check that the count of 'Unavailable' matches that of the null values. There are many columns and rows so I do not want to specify a column name etc.
Is there a way find count of all 'Unavailable' across all columns without using for loops? 
If using loops to iterate through all columns I face issue when the column contains numeric type. 
It doesn't make sense to do a value_count as I am interested in knowing only the 'Unavailable' count and not counts of all values. 
More so I feel there should be a simple way to do such thing that I may be missing.

Comment: `(df == 'Unavailable').sum().sum()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do something like this:

```
(df.astype(str)=='Unavailable').values.sum()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get an overview of all of your Values `pd.melt()` and  `pd.groupby()` might help you to explore the data

for example:

```
foo                 bar             foobar
0   Unavailable     asd             asd
1   asd             Unavailable     asd
2   asd             Unavailable     asd
3   asd             Unavailable     asd
4   Unavailable     asd             asd
5   asd             asd             asd
6   Unavailable     asd             Unavailable
7   asd             asd             Unavailable
8   asd             asd             asd
```

melt and group the df

```
df_1 = pd.melt(df, value_vars=['foo ', 'bar ', 'foobar']).groupby("value").count()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in my case I do not want to explicitly mention the columns (since I want the value to be searched across)